# Django Haystack/Solr: Filter results based on a field containing a LIST of states

Tags: django, search, solr, django-haystack

I'm working on a search feature for people names, that is filterable by the state in which they do business.  Some people do business in multiple regions, so my question is, how do store a list of states in a field in a way that allows me to do an exact search on any states in that field?

Example Data:

```
| Person Name | States     |
|=============|============|
| John Doe    | CA, NV, AZ |
| John Smith  | NY, NJ     |
|            ...           |
|=============|============|
```

Here's my code now:
    # search_indexes.py

```
class ProfileIndex(RealTimeSearchIndex):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True) # the person's name
    state = indexes.CharField(faceted=True)


    def prepare_text(self, profile):
        return profile.display_name

    def prepare_state(self, profile):
        return ???????


# search code
search_string = "John"
search_state = "CA"
search_results = SearchQuerySet().models(Profile) \
            .filter(text=search_string, state=search_state) \
            .load_all()

# Should only return John Doe because of the search_state constraint...
```

I'd like solr to parse the state names exactly, without doing any solr magic like stemming/fuzzy matching/etc...

This seems like a basic request, what am I not seeing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
state = indexes.MultiValueField()

    def prepare_state(self, obj):
        return [g.pk for g in obj.state_set.all()]
```